# Create table with record for each employee for each date

Tags: sql-server

I need to populate the following table for a date range with one record per employee for every weekday that is not a holiday. The date source is a basic calendar table.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SalaryEmpBase](
    [resource_key] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Hours] [decimal](4, 2) NOT NULL,
    [HoursType] [nvarchar](4) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

The basic insert would be:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SalaryEmpBase ([resource_key],[date],[hours],[hourstype])
SELECT
  resource_key, THISDate, 8, 'Base'
FROM
  EMPTable
WHERE
  comptype = 'Salary'
```

What is the best way to iterate through the date range  with a filter for weekday and not a holiday?

Comment: Edit your question and show what the calendar table looks like.

Comment: Inner join your calendar table with a criteria for not a holiday (assume you got some flag to mark whether it is or not)

Comment: Use GROUP BY or OVER() one of them should be enough to group the records as needed. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, the calendar table has this information, so you can just use a `cross join`.  It would look something like this:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.SalaryEmpBase ([resource_key],[date],[hours],[hourstype])
    SELECT e.resource_key, c.Date, 8, 'Base'
    FROM EMPTable e CROSS JOIN
         Calendar c
    WHERE e.comptype = 'Salary' AND
          c.date >= @StartDate AND c.date <= @EndDate AND
          c.is_holiday_flag = 0;
```

Comment: Simple and elegant. I knew I was making this harder than needed.